# How to send WPForms as pdf to email?

Tags: wordpress

I am making a wordpress website in which I am using WPForms to fill different forms. When I am sending the form, all the details are sent to the admin email as well as user email. What I want is to send all the form details in a pdf as attachment to the email. Is it possible using any plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is using [Contact Form 7](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) and the [Send PDF for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/send-pdf-for-contact-form-7/) plugins.

Both free and do exactly what you ask.